# Example of two elements ($f$ and $g$) of the ring of continuous functions such that $f$~$g$ but there is no unit $h$ such that $f=hg$

Tags: ring-theory

I was requestet to find two elements, $f$ and $g$, of the ring $C(\Bbb R)$ (with pointwise addition and multiplication), such that $f$~$g$ but there is no unit $h$ such that $f=hg$. I define ~ as $f$~$g$ $\iff$ $<g> = <f>$. As $C(\Bbb R)$ is commutative, $<f>=fC(\Bbb R)$. So we want $fC(\Bbb R)=gC(\Bbb R)$. I attempted many trivial functions f and g, but they don't give the same ideal generated. And when I feel closed to be there, I find that there is an $h$ such that $f=hg$, as in the case $f=x^2+x+1$ and $g=x^2+1$. Can someone help me? How can a find such functions? I am just beginning with ring theory, so some concepts still a little bit obscure to me, so am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the functions
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases} x+1 & x<-1 \\ 0 & -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\ x-1 & x>1 \end{cases}, \qquad g(x)=\begin{cases} -x-1 & x<-1 \\ 0 & -1\leq x \leq 1 \\ x-1 & x>1. \end{cases} $$
We will show that $f$ and $g$ satisfy the given conditions.

First, if $h$ is a unit, then either $h(x)>0$ for all $x$, or $h(x)<0$ for all $x$. Therefore, if $f=gh$, then plugging $x=-2$ gives us that $h(-2)<0$, and for $x=2$ we get $h(2)>0$. This gives us a contradiction, so such $h$ does not exists.

For the second part, let
$$ h(x)=\begin{cases} -1 & x<-1 \\ x & -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 1 & x>1 \end{cases} $$
Note that $g=fh$ and $f=gh$, and so $\langle f\rangle=\langle g \rangle$.